# Unable to resolve 'Method Not Allowed - The method is not allowed for the requested URL.' error

Tags: python, flask

I am receiving a 'Method Not Allowed - The method is not allowed for the request URL.' error when I click on the 'Logout' button on the Main page. I expect it to go to the index page but I keep receiving an error. I have tried updating the methods for Main and dropsession but neither works. Thanks!

Updated method of '/dropsession' from 'GET' to 'POST'. Still getting same error.

Updated - Fixed by removing methods from '/dropsession' and removing  tag from HTML.

main program:

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, redirect, url_for, session, g

import os

app = Flask(__name__)

app.secret_key = os.urandom(24)


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        session.pop('user', None)

        if request.form['password'] == 'admin' and request.form['username'] == 'admin':
            session['user'] = request.form['username']
            return redirect(url_for('main'))

    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/main')
def main():
    if g.user:
        return render_template('main.html', user=session['user'])
    return redirect(url_for('index'))


@app.before_request
def before_request():
    g.user = None

    if 'user' in session:
        g.user = session['user']


@app.route('/dropsession', methods=['POST'])
def dropsession():
    session.pop('user', None)
    return render_template('index.html')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Html:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/style.css" type="text/css">
<form action="main" method="POST">
<div class="main">
<div class="main-screen">
<div class="main-title">
<h1><center>Patient Hypothyroidism Probability</center></h1>
<h4>This application is designed to assist medical professional.
By using machine learning, the application will determine if the patient has
hypothyroidism.</h4>
<h4>Please enter patient information below:</h4>
<label for="age">Age: </label><input type="number" id="age" name="age" class="entryfield">
<br>
<p>On Thyroxine:</p>
<div>
<input type="radio" id="thyroxine_yes" name="thyroxine" value="1"><label>Yes</label>
<input type="radio" id="thyroxine_no" name="thyroxine" value="0"><label>No</label>
</div>
<p>On Antithyroid medication:</p>
<div>
<input type="radio" id="antithyroid_yes" name="antithyroid" value="1"><label>Yes</label>
<input type="radio" id="antithyroid_no" name="antithyroid" value="0"><label>No</label>
</div>
<p>Thyroid Surgery:</p>
<div>
<input type="radio" id="thyroid_surgery_yes" name="thyroid_surgery" value="1"><label>Yes</label>
<input type="radio" id="thyroid_surgery_no" name="thyroid_surgery" value="0"><label>No</label>
</div>
<p>Pregnant:</p>
<div>
<input type="radio" id="pregnant_yes" name="pregnant" value="1"><label>Yes</label>
<input type="radio" id="pregnant_no" name="pregnant" value="0"><label>No</label>
</div>
<p>Sick:</p>
<div>
<input type="radio" id="sick_yes" name="sick" value="1"><label>Yes</label>
<input type="radio" id="sick_no" name="sick" value="0"><label>No</label>
</div>
<p>Tumor:</p>
<div>
<input type="radio" id="tumor_yes" name="tumor" value="1"><label>Yes</label>
<input type="radio" id="tumor_no" name="tumor" value="0"><label>No</label>
</div>
<p>On Lithium:</p>
<div>
<input type="radio" id="lithium_yes" name="lithium" value="1"><label>Yes</label>
<input type="radio" id="lithium_no" name="lithium" value="0"><label>No</label>
</div>
<p>Goitre:</p>
<div>
<input type="radio" id="goitre_yes" name="goitre" value="1"><label>Yes</label>
<input type="radio" id="goitre_no" name="goitre" value="0"><label>No</label>
</div>
<br>
<p>TSH Measured:</p>
<div>
<input type="radio" id="tsh_measured_yes" name="tsh_measured" value="1"><label>Yes</label>
<input type="radio" id="tsh_measured_no" name="tsh_measured" value="0"><label>No</label>
</div>
<label for="age">TSH (if measured): </label><input type="number" id="tsh" name="tsh" class="entryfield" step="0.1">
<br>
<p>T3 Measured:</p>
<div>
<input type="radio" id="t3_measured_yes" name="t3_measured" value="1"><label>Yes</label>
<input type="radio" id="t3_measured_no" name="t3_measured" value="0"><label>No</label>
</div>
<label for="age">T3 (if measured): </label><input type="number" id="t3" name="t3" class="entryfield" step="0.1">
<br>
<p>Total T4 Measured:</p>
<div>
<input type="radio" id="tt4_measured_yes" name="tt4_measured" value="1"><label>Yes</label>
<input type="radio" id="tt4_measured_no" name="tt4_measured" value="0"><label>No</label>
</div>
<label for="age">Total T4 (if measured): </label><input type="number" id="tt4" name="tt4" class="entryfield" step="0.1">
<br>
<p>Free T4 Measured:</p>
<div>
<input type="radio" id="t4u_measured_yes" name="t4u_measured" value="1"><label>Yes</label>
<input type="radio" id="t4u_measured_no" name="t4u_measured" value="0"><label>No</label>
</div>
<label for="age">Free T4 (if measured): </label><input type="number" id="t4u" name="t4u" class="entryfield" step="0.01">
<br>
<p>Free Thyroxine Index Measured:</p>
<div>
<input type="radio" id="fti_measured_yes" name="fti_measured" value="1"><label>Yes</label>
<input type="radio" id="fti_measured_no" name="fti_measured" value="0"><label>No</label>
</div>
<label for="age">Free Thyroxine Index (if measured): </label><input type="number" id="fti" name="fti" class="entryfield" step="0.1">
</div>
<button onclick="window.location = 'http://localhost:5000/dropsession'" type="submit">Logout</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: The `/dropsession` route is defined to only accept GET requests, but you're calling it via a submit button which is a POST request.

Comment: Thanks! I updated the POST request for /dropsession but still getting the same error.

Comment: Update the code in the question to show the changes you've made.

Comment: I have updated the code with a comment describing the update. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Did you re-deploy the application and restart the web server after updating the code?

Comment: I ran the program again (from PyCharm) and refreshed the page (Ctrl+Shift+R). Is that considered re-deploy and restart? Thank you so much for your help!